# How to search with parameter colums in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to write a stored procedure in SQL Server that gets the columns as parameters. The user will select the column name from a combo box and will write the searched value for that column on a textbox.

I've been searching how to do this and so far i have this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Select_TBL_Folio]
    @cant int,
    @Column1 nvarchar(50),
    @Value1 nvarchar(50),
    @Column2 nvarchar(50),
    @Value2 nvarchar(50),
    @Column3 nvarchar(50),
    @Value3 nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @query nvarchar (max)
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    if @cant = 1
     BEGIN
        set @query = 'SELECT * FROM TBL_Folio WHERE ' + @Column1 + ' LIKE  '+ @Value1 + ' ORDER BY 1 DESC';
        exec sp_executesql @query, N' '
     END
    else 
     BEGIN
        if @cant = 2
            BEGIN
                set @query = 'SELECT * FROM TBL_Folio WHERE ' + @Column1 + ' LIKE '+ @Value1 + ' AND '  + @Column2 + ' LIKE '+ @Value2 + ' ORDER BY 1 DESC';
                exec sp_executesql @query, N' ' 
            END
        ELSE
        if @cant = 3
            BEGIN
                set @query = 'SELECT * FROM TBL_Folio WHERE ' + @Column1 + ' LIKE '+ @Value1 + ' AND '  + @Column2 + ' LIKE '+ @Value2 + ' AND '  + @Column3 + ' LIKE '+ @Value3 + ' ORDER BY 1 DESC';
                exec sp_executesql @query, N' ' 
            END
     END
END
```

The user can send 1 to 3 values, for that I have the parameter `@cant`, this code works but I want to know if there is a better way to do this or how can I improve this stored procedure.

Comment: your statement is confusing, The user will select an option in a combobox, and you want the value of that combobox to be passed to a textbox?

Comment: the user will select the column name from a combobox and will write the searched value on a textbox, this will be the parameters that the SP will receive

Comment: Can you post the schema of the `TBL_Folio` table, and maybe even a few example rows?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you have is fine if you need to do it in an SP rather than client side.  I would probabably initialize the query to the 'select * from TBL_Folio" and then append the LIKES after each if.  I would also caution against using SELECT * so your client side doesn't blow up if a field gets added to the table.

If you have a need to check a variable number of fields rather than just up to 3, you can do a table-valued parameter and build up your query by looping through.   Here is an example:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetFilteredInvoices]
@FilterColumns ColumnValueType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
declare @columnName varchar(50), @columnValue varchar(MAX), @query nvarchar(MAX), @count int
set @query='SELECT InvoiceNumber, InvoiceDate, Customer from Invoices '
set @count=0
set @columnName=''
while exists(select * from @FilterColumns where ColumnName>@ColumnName)
begin
    set @columnName=(select min(ColumnName) from @FilterColumns where ColumnName>@columnName)
    if @count=0
        set @query=@query+'WHERE '
    else
        set @query=@query+'AND '
    set @query=@query+ (select ColumnName+' Like ''%'+ColumnValue+'%'' ' from @filterColumns where ColumnName=@columnName) 
    set @count=@count+1
end
exec sp_executesql @query
END
```

Here is the table valued type I used:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[ColumnValueType] AS TABLE(
[ColumnName] [varchar](50) NULL,
[ColumnValue] [varchar](max) NULL
)
GO
```

Now this will take any number of columns and values to apply the filter.

Here is an example call to the procedure:

```
DECLARE @RC int
DECLARE @FilterColumns [dbo].[ColumnValueType]

insert into @filterColumns
Values('InvoiceNumber','345')
,('Customer','67')


EXECUTE @RC = [dbo].[GetFilteredInvoices] 
   @FilterColumns
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can perhaps improve the way that you handle your input parameters by getting rid of the `@cant` parameter. You can also improve the way that you build up the conditions, at the moment you are not handling the situations where  only `@Column2` and `@Value2` or only `@Column3` and `@Value3` is set (perhaps it is not needed in your case, but it is still good practice to handle these types of scenarios)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_Select_TBL_Folio
    @Column1 NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @Value1 NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @Column2 NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @Value2 NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @Column3 NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @Value3 NVARCHAR(50) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE 
        @P1 NVARCHAR(500),
        @P2 NVARCHAR(500),
        @P3 NVARCHAR(500),
        @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

        IF (@Column1 IS NULL OR @Column1 = '') AND (@Value1 IS NULL OR @Value1 = '')
        BEGIN
             -- This will build up dynamic SQL to always select records even if @Column1
             -- and @Value1 is not set. This obvisously all depends on your requirements
             -- and if you still need to select records if the parameters are not set, otherwise
             -- it can be changed to ' WHERE ThePrimaryKeyColumn = 0'
             SET @P1 = ' WHERE ThePrimaryKeyColumn > 0'
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @P1 = 'WHERE ' + @Column1 + ' LIKE ' + '''' + @Value1 + ''''
        END

        IF (@Column2 IS NULL OR @Column2 = '') AND (@Value2 IS NULL OR @Value2 = '')
        BEGIN
            SET @P2 = ''
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @P2 = ' AND ' + @Column2 + ' LIKE ' + '''' + @Value2 + ''''
        END

        IF (@Column3 IS NULL OR @Column3 = '') AND (@Value3 IS NULL OR @Value3 = '')
        BEGIN
            SET @P3 = ''
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @P3 = ' AND ' + @Column3 + ' LIKE ' + '''' + @Value3 + ''''
        END

        SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM TBL_Folio
                [P1]
                [P2]
                [P3]'

    -- Here we set all the conditions
    SET @SQL = REPLACE(@SQL, '[P1]', @P1);
    SET @SQL = REPLACE(@SQL, '[P2]', @P2);
    SET @SQL = REPLACE(@SQL, '[P3]', @P3);

    -- This will be replaced by EXEC(@SQL)
    PRINT @SQL
 END
```

So now you can for instance execute

```
 EXEC SP_Select_TBL_Folio
```

which will give you

```
 SELECT * FROM TBL_Folio
 WHERE ThePrimaryKeyColumn > 0
```

or you can execute

```
EXEC SP_Select_TBL_Folio 'Column1','Value1'
```

which will give you

```
SELECT * FROM TBL_Folio
WHERE Column1 LIKE 'Value1'
```

or you can execute

```
EXEC SP_Select_TBL_Folio NULL,NULL,'Column2','Value2'
```

which will give you

```
SELECT * FROM TBL_Folio
WHERE ThePrimaryKeyColumn > 0
AND Column2 LIKE 'Value2'
```

I'm not going to list all the permutations, I'm sure you get my point.